# how to change the Spree default home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spree

I want to change the root path of spree site to a static page.

Can anyone please tell how can I change the spree default home page?

Comment: Could it be : `public/index.html`?

Comment: yes it can be: public/index.html or it can be any other static page.

Comment: try using it
[spree_static_content](https://github.com/spree/spree_static_content)

Comment: Really better idea , @anonymousxxx. Probably a good answer too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy solution is : in your `public` directory you place the static `index.html` . Then in your `routes.rb` :

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/store'
```

with the idea to point a link from your `index.html`  to `yoursite.com/store` .

Comment: do you have any idea about dynamic page also that can be placed at root path.

Comment: Absolutely , the pattern is the same . You have a `store` route , which points your Spree engine mount point . Your Rials generated (dynamical) content might be a resource , which have `index` pointing to `root` of your app . Something like : `root :to => 'your_resource#index'` at the bottom of your `routes.rb`. Assuming that in your `index` template there is a link to store.

Comment: i have sessions controller :  [class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def home
  
 end
end  ] i want sessions/home at root page... i mention in routes : [root :to => 'sessions#home'],but its no working

Comment: Why demolish the default rails behaviour? The spree::homecontroller#index action will render the spree/home/index.html.erb template file with or without layout without problem, just place the file there and it will render. It makes no sense to place a view inside the public folder when it doesn't have to be there. Bad answer in my opninion

Comment: Do you mind if you read the question and comments once again?

Comment: Messing with pages in 'public' is not quite 'rails way'